# WordPress SVN returning PHP parse error (checked against PHP 5.4), but no parse errors found

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am attempting to upload wordpress plugin via SVN. The plugin is working perfectly fine on my live server (PHP 5.3) and is also working fine on the testing servers (PHP 5.4 and PHP 5.5) which are set to display all errors with E_ALL. No PHP errors are being returned on any server, yet the WP SCN hook is detecting a parse error:

The code of the plugin is:

```PHP
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: GitHub Mini Profile Widget
Plugin URI: http://f13dev.com/wordpress-plugin-github-profile-widget/
Description: Add a mini version of your GitHub profile to a widget on a WordPress powered site.
Version: 1.0
Author: Jim Valentine - f13dev
Author URI: http://f13dev.com
Text Domain: f13-github-mini-profile-widget
License: GPLv3
*/

/*
Copyright 2016 James Valentine - f13dev (jv@f13dev.com)
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
any later version.
This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
GNU General Public License for more details.
You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/**
* Register the widget
*/
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("GitHub_Mini_Profile_Widget");'));
// Register the css
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gmpw_style');

/**
 * A function to register and enque the stylesheet
 */
function gmpw_style()
{
    wp_register_style( 'f13-gmpw-style', plugins_url('github-profile-widget.css', __FILE__) );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'f13-gmpw-style' );
}

/**
 * A class to generate a GitHub profile widget
 */
class GitHub_Mini_Profile_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    /** Basic Widget Settings */
    const WIDGET_NAME = "GitHub Mini Profile Widget";
    const WIDGET_DESCRIPTION = "Add a mini version of your GitHub profile to your website.";

    var $textdomain;
    var $fields;

    /**
    * Create a new instance of the GitHub widget
    * by setting the widget setting fields.
    */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->textdomain = strtolower(get_class($this));

        //Add fields
        $this->add_field('title', 'Widget title', '', 'text');
        $this->add_field('github_user', 'GitHub ID', '', 'text');
        $this->add_field('github_token', 'GitHub API Token', '', 'text');
        $this->add_field('github_timeout', 'Cache timeout (minutes)', '30', 'number');
        //Init the widget
        parent::__construct($this->textdomain, __(self::WIDGET_NAME, $this->textdomain), array( 'description' => __(self::WIDGET_DESCRIPTION, $this->textdomain), 'classname' => $this->textdomain));
    }

    /**
    * Widget frontend
    *
    * @param array $args
    * @param array $instance
    */
    public function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if (!empty($title))
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        $this->widget_output($args, $instance);

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
    * Adds a text field to the widget
    *
    * @param $field_name
    * @param string $field_description
    * @param string $field_default_value
    * @param string $field_type
    */
    private function add_field($field_name, $field_description, $field_default_value, $field_type)
    {
        if(!is_array($this->fields))
        $this->fields = array();

        $this->fields[$field_name] = array('name' => $field_name, 'description' => $field_description, 'default_value' => $field_default_value, 'type' => $field_type);
    }

    /**
    * Widget backend
    *
    * @param array $instance
    * @return string|void
    */
    public function form( $instance )
    {
        /**
        * Create a header with basic instructions.
        */
        ?>
        <br/>
        Use this widget to add a mini version of your GitHub profile as a widget<br/>
        <br/>
        Get your access token from <a href="https://github.com/settings/tokens" target="_blank">https://github.com/settings/tokens</a>.<br/>
        <br/>
        <?php
        /* Generate admin form fields */
        foreach($this->fields as $field_name => $field_data)
        {
            if($field_data['type'] === 'text')
            {
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($field_name); ?>"><?php _e($field_data['description'], $this->textdomain ); ?></label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($field_name); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($field_name); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr(isset($instance[$field_name]) ? $instance[$field_name] : $field_data['default_value']); ?>" />
                </p>
                <?php

            }
            else
            if($field_data['type'] === 'number')
            {
                ?>
                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($field_name); ?>"><?php _e($field_data['description'], $this->textdomain ); ?></label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id($field_name); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name($field_name); ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo esc_attr(isset($instance[$field_name]) ? $instance[$field_name] : $field_data['default_value']); ?>" />
                </p>
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                /* Otherwise show an error */
                echo __('Error - Field type not supported', $this->textdomain) . ': ' . $field_data['type'];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Updating widget by replacing the old instance with new
    *
    * @param array $new_instance
    * @param array $old_instance
    * @return array
    */
    public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        return $new_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Function to load the widget
     */
    private function widget_output($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($instance);

        // Set the cache name for this instance of the widget
        $cache = get_transient('wpgpw' . md5(serialize($github_user)));

        if ($cache)
        {
                // If the cache exists, return it rather than re-creating it
                echo $cache;
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the API results
            $userAPI = $this->f13_get_github_api('https://api.github.com/users/' . $github_user, $github_token);
            $widget = '
                <div class="gmpw-container">
                    <a href="https://github.com/' . $userAPI['login'] . '" class="gmpw-head-link">
                        <div class="gmpw-head">
                          <div class="gmpw-headder">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" height="18" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="18"><path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0 0 16 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"></path></svg>
                                GitHub
                            </div>
                            <div class="gmpw-profile-picture">
                                <img src="' . $userAPI['avatar_url'] . '"  />
                            </div>
                            <div class="gmpw-names">
                                <div class="gmpw-name">
                                    ' . $userAPI['name'] . '
                                </div>
                                <div class="gmpw-user">
                                    @' . $userAPI['login'] . '
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>';

                    if ($userAPI['bio'] != '')
                    {
                        $widget .= '
                        <div class="gmpw-bio">
                            <span>Bio: </span>
                            ' . $userAPI['bio'] . '
                        </div>';
                    }

                    $widget .= '
                    <div class="gmpw-info">
                        <span class="gmpw-info-user">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="14"><path d="M4.75 4.95C5.3 5.59 6.09 6 7 6c.91 0 1.7-.41 2.25-1.05A1.993 1.993 0 0 0 13 4c0-1.11-.89-2-2-2-.41 0-.77.13-1.08.33A3.01 3.01 0 0 0 7 0C5.58 0 4.39 1 4.08 2.33 3.77 2.13 3.41 2 3 2c-1.11 0-2 .89-2 2a1.993 1.993 0 0 0 3.75.95zm5.2-1.52c.2-.38.59-.64 1.05-.64.66 0 1.2.55 1.2 1.2 0 .65-.55 1.2-1.2 1.2-.65 0-1.17-.53-1.19-1.17.06-.19.11-.39.14-.59zM7 .98c1.11 0 2.02.91 2.02 2.02 0 1.11-.91 2.02-2.02 2.02-1.11 0-2.02-.91-2.02-2.02C4.98 1.89 5.89.98 7 .98zM3 5.2c-.66 0-1.2-.55-1.2-1.2 0-.65.55-1.2 1.2-1.2.45 0 .84.27 1.05.64.03.2.08.41.14.59C4.17 4.67 3.66 5.2 3 5.2zM13 6H1c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v3c0 .55.45 1 1 1v2c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-1h1v3c0 .55.45 1 1 1h2c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-3h1v1c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1v-2c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V7c0-.55-.45-1-1-1zM3 13H2v-3H1V7h2v6zm7-2H9V9H8v6H6V9H5v2H4V7h6v4zm3-1h-1v3h-1V7h2v3z"></path></svg>
                            ' . $userAPI['login'] . '<br />';

                            if ($userAPI['location'] != '')
                            {
                                $widget .= '
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="12"><path d="M6 0C2.69 0 0 2.5 0 5.5 0 10.02 6 16 6 16s6-5.98 6-10.5C12 2.5 9.31 0 6 0zm0 14.55C4.14 12.52 1 8.44 1 5.5 1 3.02 3.25 1 6 1c1.34 0 2.61.48 3.56 1.36.92.86 1.44 1.97 1.44 3.14 0 2.94-3.14 7.02-5 9.05zM8 5.5c0 1.11-.89 2-2 2-1.11 0-2-.89-2-2 0-1.11.89-2 2-2 1.11 0 2 .89 2 2z"></path></svg>
                                ' . $userAPI['location'] . '<br />';
                            }

                            if ($userAPI['email'] != '')
                            {
                                $widget .= '
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="14"><path d="M0 4v8c0 .55.45 1 1 1h12c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V4c0-.55-.45-1-1-1H1c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1zm13 0L7 9 1 4h12zM1 5.5l4 3-4 3v-6zM2 12l3.5-3L7 10.5 8.5 9l3.5 3H2zm11-.5l-4-3 4-3v6z"></path></svg>
                                <a href="mailto:' . $userAPI['email'] . '">' . $userAPI['email'] . '</a>';
                            }

                        $widget .= '
                        </span>
                        <span class="gmpw-info-website">';

                            if ($userAPI['blog'] != '')
                            {
                                $widget .= '
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="16"><path d="M4 9h1v1H4c-1.5 0-3-1.69-3-3.5S2.55 3 4 3h4c1.45 0 3 1.69 3 3.5 0 1.41-.91 2.72-2 3.25V8.59c.58-.45 1-1.27 1-2.09C10 5.22 8.98 4 8 4H4c-.98 0-2 1.22-2 2.5S3 9 4 9zm9-3h-1v1h1c1 0 2 1.22 2 2.5S13.98 12 13 12H9c-.98 0-2-1.22-2-2.5 0-.83.42-1.64 1-2.09V6.25c-1.09.53-2 1.84-2 3.25C6 11.31 7.55 13 9 13h4c1.45 0 3-1.69 3-3.5S14.5 6 13 6z"></path></svg>
                                <a href="' . $userAPI['blog'] . '">' . $userAPI['blog'] . '</a><br />';
                            }

                            $widget .= '
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="14"><path d="M8 8h3v2H7c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V4h2v4zM7 2.3c3.14 0 5.7 2.56 5.7 5.7s-2.56 5.7-5.7 5.7A5.71 5.71 0 0 1 1.3 8c0-3.14 2.56-5.7 5.7-5.7zM7 1C3.14 1 0 4.14 0 8s3.14 7 7 7 7-3.14 7-7-3.14-7-7-7z"></path></svg>
                            Joined on ' . $this->gitDate($userAPI['created_at']) . '
                        </span>
                    </div>';
                    // Change to if show numbers
                    if (true)
                    {
                        $starredCount = count($this->f13_get_github_api('https://api.github.com/users/' . $github_user . '/starred', $github_token));
                        $widget .= '
                        <div class="gmpw-numbers">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span>
                                    <span>' . $userAPI['followers'] . '</span><br />
                                    Follower
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span>
                                    <span>' . $starredCount . '</span><br />
                                    Starred
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#">
                                <span>
                                    <span>' . $userAPI['following'] . '</span><br />
                                    Following
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>';
                    }
                    $widget .= '
                    <div class="gmpw-repos">
                        <span class="gmpw-repos-public">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="octicon octicon-repo" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="12"><path d="M4 9H3V8h1v1zm0-3H3v1h1V6zm0-2H3v1h1V4zm0-2H3v1h1V2zm8-1v12c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H6v2l-1.5-1.5L3 16v-2H1c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1V1c0-.55.45-1 1-1h10c.55 0 1 .45 1 1zm-1 10H1v2h2v-1h3v1h5v-2zm0-10H2v9h9V1z"></path></svg>
                            <a href="https://gists.github.com/' . $userAPI['login'] . '">' . $userAPI['public_repos'] . ' Public Repos</a>
                            </span>
                        <span class="gmpw-repos-gists">
                            <svg aria-hidden="true" height="16" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 12 16" width="16"><path d="M7.5 5L10 7.5 7.5 10l-.75-.75L8.5 7.5 6.75 5.75 7.5 5zm-3 0L2 7.5 4.5 10l.75-.75L3.5 7.5l1.75-1.75L4.5 5zM0 13V2c0-.55.45-1 1-1h10c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v11c0 .55-.45 1-1 1H1c-.55 0-1-.45-1-1zm1 0h10V2H1v11z"></path></svg>
                            <a href="https://gists.github.com/' . $userAPI['login'] . '">' . $userAPI['public_gists'] . ' Public Gists</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ';
            $timeout = $github_timeout * 60;
            if ($timeout == 0)
            {
                $timeout = 1;
            }
            set_transient('wpgpw' . md5(serialize($github_user)), $widget, $timeout);
            echo $widget;
        }
    }

    private function f13_get_github_api($url, $token)
     {
             // Start curl
             $curl = curl_init();
             // Set curl options
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

             // Check if a token is set
             if (preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $token) != '' || $token != null)
             {
                     // If a token is set attempt to send it in the header
                     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                             'Content-Type: application/json',
                             'Accept: application/json',
                             'Authorization: token ' . $token
                     ));
             }
             else
             {
                     // If no token is set, send the header as unauthenticated,
                     // some features may not work and a lower rate limit applies.
                     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                             'Content-Type: application/json',
                             'Accept: application/json'
                     ));
             }
             // Set the user agent
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
             // Set curl to return the response, rather than print it
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

             // Get the results
             $result = curl_exec($curl);

             // Close the curl session
             curl_close($curl);

             // Decode the results
             $result = json_decode($result, true);

             // Return the results
             return $result;
     }

     private function gitDate($date)
     {
         $dateArray = explode('-', $date);
         // Add the day to the string
         $date = substr($dateArray[2], 0, 2) . ' ';
         // Add the month to the string
         $date .= $this->getMonth($dateArray[1]) . ' ';
         // Add the year
         $date .= $dateArray[0];
         return $date;
     }

     private function getMonth($month)
     {
         if ($month == 01)
         {
             return 'Jan';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 02)
         {
             return 'Feb';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 03)
         {
             return 'Mar';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 04)
         {
             return 'Apr';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 05)
         {
             return 'May';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 06)
         {
             return 'Jun';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 07)
         {
             return 'Jul';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 08)
         {
             return 'Aug';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 09)
         {
             return 'Sep';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 10)
         {
             return 'Oct';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 11)
         {
             return 'Nov';
         }
         else
         if ($month == 12)
         {
             return 'Dec';
         }
     }

}
```

Is there any obvious reason why this would be returning a parse error via the WP SVN as I can't find anything amiss.

Thank you
Jim

-- Edit --
Thought I aught to add as well that the SVN is just returning an error, it is not highlighting any specific lines of code which isn't helping me much.

-- Another edit --
I've now tried the same process on Debian x64 using SVN 1.8.10 and am getting the same error, so I believe this not to be a problem at the SVN client end.

The message that is being returned is:

```terminal
Transmitting file data .......svn: E165001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E165001: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output:

***********************************
PHP error in: f13-github-mini-profile-widget/trunk/github-profile-widget.php:
Errors parsing f13-github-mini-profile-widget/trunk/github-profile-widget.php
***********************************
```

Comment: Which tool you are using for SVN ?

Comment: @Milap I am using SVN 1.8.13 for MacOSX x86_64 from Apache Software Foundation, installed via HomeBrew - edit - I've been using this version for 3 other WordPress repositories, but will transfer the files to my linux laptop after the school run and try from there to be on the safe side :D

Comment: I have uploaded my own plugin using Windows & Linux without any issues, so i guess it is due to MacOSX issue. (I am not sure though)

Comment: @Milap I've just tried the process on my Linux laptop, running Debian 8.5 x64, SVN 1.8.10, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now discovered the issue with my code (or PHP7).

It turns out that the WordPress SVN now lints code with PHP7, after installing PHP7 on my testing machine and linting the code it turns out that the function getMonth() was causing the issue due to the numeric literals being prefixed with '0'

By enclosing the numbers in quotation marks the issue has been resolved.

e.g. changing:

```php
if ($month == 01)
{
  return 'Jan';
}
```

to:

```php
if ($month == '01')
{
  return 'Jan';
}
```

Comment: Okay, you can read here for more details https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2016/07/14/known-issues-with-pre-commit-to-the-plugins-svn/

Comment: @Milap Thank you very much for the link, that will no doubt be very helpful with some of the other apps I plan to build, it should hopefully save me a lot of time and frustration. Jim